# HTML email newsletter not responsive / scaling down to fit screen on Android 4.4 (works in other mobile clients)

Tags: android, html, css, html-email, newsletter

Ive hand coded an email newsletter than works fine in various email clients apart from Android 4.4 where im getting an a bug where the content wont scale down to fit on a mobile screen. Ideally it would be responsive , but if not simply scaled down would would fit. It works fine in other mobile browsers - gmail, iOS mail etc.

Below is a screenshot of the test from Litmus (email testing service). Ive blurred out the content, but as you can see only half the content is showing up with the rest of it lost on the right hand side because it hasn't scaled down.

ANDROID 4.4 Screenshot from Litmus :

[image: Android 4.4 test]

Here is the HTML im using (again content has been removed) but html structure and css is shown. Ive also tried added a meta viewport tag : `<meta  name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`, but to no avail. Any ideas what i could change ?

```
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            .dm-user-inserted-image{
                height:auto !important;
                max-width:600px !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width:480px) {
            table {
                width: 100%!important;
            }

            td {
                width: 100%!important;
            }

        }


        .header-logo {

        }

        a {
            border-style: none;
        }

        a img {
            border-style: none;
        }

        .heading-light {

        }

        .heading-bold {
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: 600;
            color: #000000;
        }


        .horizontal-rule {
            background:none;
            border-top:solid 1px #CCCCCC;
            border-top-width:1px 0 0 0;

            border-left:none;
            border-right:none;
            border-bottom:none;

            height:1px;
            width:100%;
            margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
            padding-top:10px;
            padding-bottom:10px;
        }


        .header-message {
            font-family: Helvetica-Light, "Helvetica Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #666666;
            display:block;
            font-weight: 500;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 30px;
        }


        .main-message {
            font-family: Helvetica-Light, "Helvetica Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #666666;
            display:block;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 1.6;
        }

        .link-message {
            font-family: Helvetica-Light, "Helvetica Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #666666;
            display:block;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 1.6;
        }

        .footer-details {
            font-family: Helvetica-Light, "Helvetica Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #666666;
            display:block;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 18px;
        }

        .footer-unsub {
            font-family: Helvetica-Light, "Helvetica Light", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #666666;
            display:block;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 18px;
        }
    </style>

</head>




<body style="text-align:center;" >


<center style="max-width:600px;display:inline-block;" >


    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="responsive-table">


        <tbody>


            <tr height="30" width="100%">&nbsp;</tr>


                    <tr align="center">
                        <td class="header-logo">
                            <a href="" border="0" style="border-style:none;" >
                                <img width="65" style="border-style:none;" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>


            <tr height="50" width="100%" class="bottom-border">&nbsp;</tr>




                    <tr align="center">
                    <!--[if gte mso 12]>
                        <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                        <![endif]-->


                        <td class="horizontal-rule" style="background-color:transparent;background-image:none;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:top left;background-attachment:scroll;border-width:1px 0 0 0;border-style:solid;border-color:#CCCCCC;height:1px;width:100%;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-left:0px;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;border-top-width:1px 0 0 0;border-top-style:solid;border-top-color:#CCCCCC;border-left-style:none;border-right-style:none;border-bottom-style:none;" >
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>


                            <!--[if gte mso 12]>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                    </tr>






            <tr height="10" width="100%" class="bottom-border">&nbsp;</tr>


            <!--[if gte mso 12]>
                    <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                    <![endif]-->


                    <tr align="center">
                        <td class="header-message" style="font-family:Helvetica-Light, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:20px;color:#666666;display:block;font-weight:500;text-align:center;line-height:30px;" >

                            <span class="heading-light">TEXT CONTENT<br></span>
                            <span class="heading-bold" style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight:600;color:#000000;" >"Best Interior TEXT CONTENT</span>

                        </td>
                    </tr>


            <tr height="30" width="100%">&nbsp;</tr>


                    <tr align="center">
                        <td class="main-message" style="font-family:Helvetica-Light, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#666666;display:block;text-align:center;line-height:1.6;" >
                            TEXT CONTENT
                        </td>
                    </tr>



            <tr height="20" width="100%">&nbsp;</tr>



                    <tr align="center">
                        <td class="main-message" style="font-family:Helvetica-Light, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#666666;display:block;text-align:center;line-height:1.6;" >
                            TEXT CONTENT
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <!--[if gte mso 12]>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <![endif]-->




            <tr height="20" width="100%">&nbsp;</tr>


                    <tr align="center">
                        <td class="link-message" style="font-family:Helvetica-Light, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#666666;display:block;text-align:center;line-height:1.6;" >
                            <a href=""></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>



            <tr height="30" width="100%">&nbsp;</tr>



                    <tr align="center">
                        <td class="photo">
                            <a href="" border="0" style="border-style:none;" >
                                <img width="600" style="border-style:none;" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>



            <tr height="18" width="100%">&nbsp;</tr>



                    <tr align="center">
                        <td class="photo">
                            <a href="" border="0" style="border-style:none;" >
                                <img width="600" style="border-style:none;" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>



            <tr height="18" width="100%">&nbsp;</tr>



                    <tr align="center">
                        <td class="photo">
                            <a href="" border="0" style="border-style:none;" >
                                <img width="600" style="border-style:none;" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>



            <tr height="18" width="100%">&nbsp;</tr>


                    <tr align="center">
                        <td class="photo">
                            <a href="" border="0" style="border-style:none;" >
                                <img width="600" style="border-style:none;" />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>



            <tr height="18" width="100%">&nbsp;</tr>


                    <tr align="center">
                        <td class="footer-details" style="font-family:Helvetica-Light, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#666666;display:block;text-align:center;line-height:18px;" >
                           FOOTER CONTENT
                        </td>
                    </tr>


        </tbody>

    </table>


</center>



</body>
```

Comment: my first thought is that the images have a set width of `600px` try replacing that with 100%

Comment: @Aaron - Thanks that resolved this issue, it opened up another where my images were now really large (as i had the actual images at 1200px width so they would be retina when viewed on ipad etc) to get around this i just resized the image to 600px. Do you think there is a way i could keep the images as retina, whilst getting your `width:100%` fix to still work ?

Answer (score 2):

You need add to   `@media screen and (max-width:480px)`

```
img{
    max-width:100% !important;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Because you need make the images responsive too